# validation for all rows of a column in excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Creating, for example, a date validation for one rows of one cell in excel 2010 is no problem. Can I automatically apply this validation rule to all subsequent rows of that column when I create an excel sheet from this template?

Comment: You can loop through the cells and apply your rule within the loop.

Comment: loop when? Whilst I create the template? How far would you loop then to apply it to all rows?

Comment: You can identify the last row of the column (e.g., `finalRow = cells(65000,1).end(xlup).row`) and loop from `1 to finalRow`.

Comment: Thanks please feel free to post an answer

Comment: I found a very easy way: select first cell after column heading then press crtl + shift + down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the last row of a column, like so

```
finalRow = cells(1000000,1).end(xlup).row
```

and then loop through the column to apply your validation to every cell in that column. So,

```
for i = 1 to finalRow
  'your validation code here which will refer to the ith row (e.g., cells(i,1))
  'column A = 1; column B = 2, and so on
next i
```

Hope that helps.